# What's the Pythonic way of supporting constants across modules in one project as well as across projects?

Tags: python, constants

I'm using pycharm if that matters. In one project, I have several python files and I'd like to use a set of constants across all of them. What is the pythonic way of doing that since my attempt fails for a reason unknown to me?

constants.py

```
WIDTH = 3
```

main.py

```
import constants

print(WIDTH)
```

This fails for unresolved reference WIDTH

Also, I have another project that I'd like to use the same constants in it. How is that typically handled since files are in different directories? I want to believe that there's a way to not duplicate the constants.py file.

Comment: try `from constants import WIDTH` - or, write `import constants` and then refer to `constants.WIDTH`.

Comment: or `from constants import *` but I dont like doing `import *`

Comment: OK, I get it. I think I get it. It's not like a C #include directive. By just import, I get access to the items, but have to explicitly name them. If I import a named item from constants, I get to use the plain name without the module prefix. If I import *, it's like importing every named item individually. Right?

Comment: @BillGradwohl https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html